# Mercury mode colors

Tags: faces

I cannot get colors to work in `mercury-mode`. Mercury is supported under prolog-mode and in the source of prolog-mode there is quite a bit of it defined(eg. see below).

```lisp
        ;; Mercury specific patterns
        (types
         (if (eq prolog-system 'mercury)
             (list
              (regexp-opt prolog-types-i 'words)
              0 'font-lock-type-face)))
        (modes
         (if (eq prolog-system 'mercury)
             (list
              (regexp-opt prolog-mode-specificators-i 'words)
              0 'font-lock-constant-face)))
        (directives
         (if (eq prolog-system 'mercury)
             (list
              (regexp-opt prolog-directives-i 'words)
              0 'prolog-warning-face)))
```

When I try using it, only face other than the `default` is the `font-lock-comment-face`. I am not familiar with writing or debugging emacs modes. How should I approach debugging this problem? If any one is using mercury-mode and got it working with colors please tell me how.

Comment: Does `M-x list-faces-display` list the faces you need? If not, maybe check file `prolog.el`, to see whether/where/how they're defined.

Comment: Yes all the required faces are in `list-faces-display` when the `prolog-mode` is first loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the bug and fixed it [here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=45747).